# When range hits 100, go to next page

Tags: javascript, redirect, range

```
<input type="range" id="myRange" min="0" max="100">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myRange").value;

    if(x == 100) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "NEW PAGE";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Try Again";
    }
}
</script>
```

When the user sets the range to 100, it should open up a new page.

I know that the code does not do that yet but when I search for a solution, I'm getting nothing!

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: @DrewKennedy - not true. `==` will compare regardless of type (type inference). `'100' == 100` would evaluate to `true`. `===` would mean `x` would have to be parsed first.

Comment: @Darren Welp, you learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect to the new page when `x == 100` using :

```
window.location.replace("new_link");
//OR
window.location.href = "new_link";
```

**Full code :**

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myRange").value;

    if(x == 100) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "NEW PAGE";

        window.location.replace("new_link");
        //OR
        window.location.href = "new_link";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Try Again";
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Per my comment on the question - x doesn't need parsing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, as-is and it's working fine. I have added a `window.open()` call for example on opening a new window.

Slide the slider all the way to the right, then click your button.

Perhaps update your question with what you're actually doing and hoping to achieve.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myRange").value;

    if(x == 100) {
        window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "New Page (new window doesnt work on this site)";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Try Again";
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="myRange" min="0" max="100">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Nazar Abubaker,

Follow this example:

```js
function myFunction(newValue) {
         document.getElementById('textInput').value = newValue;
         if(newValue == 100) alert('New Page!');
}
```

```html
<input type="range" name="myRange" min="0" max="100" onchange="myFunction(this.value);">
<input type="text" id="textInput" value="">
```

You can set hidden to textInput:

```
<input type="text" id="textInput" value="" hidden>
```

I hope this helps...

Good Luck!